# Query single value from firebase, React Native-Error, undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a value from a document in collection, in fire base, particularly "currentKilos":

[image: fire base collection]

I am using the below function to query it:

```
showKiols = () => {
  db.collection('users').doc(this.props.user.uid).collection('mainData').doc('currentKilos').get().then.subscribe(value=> {
        this.updatedKilos = value;
        alert(this.updatedKilos);           
    })      
}
```

However, I am getting attached error:

[image: error]

Also, I tried below function as well, but it is not working:

```
db.collection('users').doc(this.props.user.uid).collection('mainData').doc('currentKilos').valueChanges().subscribe(value => {
this.updatedKilos = value.currentKilos;
    alert(this.updatedKilos)
})
```

FYI, this is the function to add currentKilos to firebase, and it is working fine:

```
updateKilos = () => {
        db.collection('users').doc(this.props.user.uid).collection('mainData').doc('currentKilos').set({ currentKilos: this.state.currentKilos })
        alert('Data Updated')
    }
```

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you get `get().then.subscribe()` from, but at the very least that `then` should be `then((value)=>{...})`.

Try the following:

```
showKiols = () => {
db.collection('users')
 .doc(this.props.user.uid)
 .collection('mainData')
 .doc('currentKilos')
 .get()
 .then(value => {
     this.updatedKilos = value.data();
     alert(this.updatedKilos);           
 })
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your support. But this is giving the value as "Object Object". And when I change the function to be as below :

showKiols = () => {
 db.collection('users').doc(this.props.user.uid).collection('mainData').doc('currentKilos').get().then(value=> {
  this.updatedKilos = value.currentKilos;
  alert(this.updatedKilos);
   
  })
  
 }

it is giving undefined

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include `.data()` from the `value` returned. Try that now.

Comment: No, need to apology, and I really appreciate your support. It is still giving "Object Object". I even tried to use JSON.stringfy(this.updatedKilos), but not working as well

Comment: I tried again, with below code, and it is working :) 

 showKiols = () => {
 db.collection('users').doc(this.props.user.uid).collection('mainData').doc('currentKilos').get().then(value=> {
  this.updatedKilos = value.data();
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.updatedKilos));
   
  })
  
 }

You really made my day :)